# If/else statement with foreach item in database possible?

Tags: php, if-statement

A link will be `index.php?page=PAGENAME`. The `PAGENAME` is mostly stored in the database, but some are static. I want an if/else statement to echo the title. The static part is not so hard.

```
function current_page() {
  $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  $goal = explode("?page=", $uri);
  $keyone = $goal[1];
  return $keyone;
}
```

This will only show what comes after `?page=` so I have the pagename. Some static pages are dashboard and settings. The following if statement is used to show the title of the static pages:

```
$current = current_page();
if ($current == 'dashboard') {
 echo 'Dashboard';
}
elseif ($current == 'settings') {
 echo 'Settings';
}
```

Now the part I can't seem to get to work is that for every country stored in the database there should be an `elseif` statement. The `PAGENAME` is the country iso code which is stored in the database (as countryISO). But when making an database connection in the if `if/else` statement an error occur saying `unexpected 'elseif'`.

I'm trying to create a `foreach` for every row in the database with the data.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $iso = $row['countryISO'];
  elseif ($current == $iso) {
    echo $row['countryname'];
  }
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: you know that your way of getting the passed property ('page') is .... hm... strange, overworked, ... - you have it here: `$_GET['page']`

Comment: and for your error: you can only use 'elseif'  if you have an 'if' before. See the manual: [Controlstructures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: Instead of the `function current_page()` you can use `$_GET['page']` to obtain the current page's name. Also in your loop, replace `elseif` with just an `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $iso = $row['countryISO'];
  if ($current == $iso) {
    echo $row['countryname'];
  }
}
$conn->close();
```

Instead of using 'elseif', use if to check if the $current is the same as $iso. One thing you still need to do is to define $current.